# ODOO12: How retrieve the id of logged-in user?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, odoo-12

I want to retrieve the id of logged-in user in Odoo 12 but I have many errors. This my code:

user_id = http.request.env.context.get('uid')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```py
user_id = http.request.env.user.id
```